# Pass object properties to function for indexing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an original version of a website, of which some elements should be changed depending on the landing page url.
If you land on root url of the page, you will see the original version. If you land on `url.com/variant1` some of the text elements are changed, but not all.
I created an object that holds all the values. So it looks something like this:

```
const websiteData = {
  original: {
    landingPage: {
      primaryHeadline: (
        <h1>Hello to original</h1>
      ),
      secondaryHeadline: (
        <h2>How you doing?</h2>
      ),
    }
  },
  variant1: {
    landingPage: {
      secondaryHeadline: (<h2>How are you?</h2>)
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to render based on the variant, so for example if I wanted to get the primary headline for the current version of the site, I would index it like so:
`websiteData[version]["landingPage"]["primaryHeadline"]`.
However when there is no value available for a variant, I want it to default back to the original version.
I thought of writing a function for this case, which should basically return either the variant version of an element or, if that does not exist, the original.

```
const getElementFromVersionOrOriginal = (version, properties) => {
   websiteData[version][properties] ? 
   return websiteData[version][properties] :
   return websiteData["original"][properties]
```

Obviously the above version doesn't work, since I don't know how to feed in the properties. I'm generally also questioning whether my setup is making any sense or whether there is a significantly better way.
My last resort would be to just write it out for each case like so:

```
{funnelData[version]["landingPage"]["primaryHeadline"] ? 
 funnelData[version]["landingPage"]["primaryHeadline"] :
 funnelData[original]["landingPage"]["primaryHeadline"]}
```

but then if there isn't a `landingPage` property on one of the versions, it would already fail saying it can't find `primaryHeadline` in undefined, right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need:

```
const getElementFromVersionOrOriginal = (version, properties) => {
   return (websiteData[version] || websiteData["original"])[properties];
```